# How can I re-program/flash a backup of the bios?

Tags: backup, motherboard, bios, flashing, cmos

I have some computers that have a particular bios setting that keeps everything running smoothly.  The setting is not the default setting for the motherboard.  So, when the CMOS battery dies, the setting is erased and causes the user problems.  How can I backup the bios and settings I have now, and flash that file onto my entire stock of computers?  I have attempted to use awdflash to backup my bios and then attempt to write that backup to the ROM chip, but I keep getting an error.  It tells me that my file number doesn't match the system, or something like that.  Basically, the file is incompatible with the chip.  But I just backed it up from that chip.  If anyone can shed some light on this for me it would be helpful.

Comment: How often do your CMOS batteries die!? I've had my computer for like 10 years now and it hasn't died, and I have computers from like 1995 that still have a good battery

Comment: If you are using the software from the actual bio manufacturer then what you described should work.  You say you use awdflash, so I am assuming that your systems have award bios correct?

Comment: What motherboard are we talking about? Please post the information.

Comment: @earlz: I've had batteries die well before 5 years, and others that lasted a long time.  Quality depends on the brand.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that BIOS flashing utilities only backup/restore the ROM image, *not* the settings.

Answer (score 1):

AWRDACPI does not sound like a model number - are you getting this from System Information?

If so then it is probably a generic report of an Award Bios with ACPI support.

A quick google on VIA694 gives this:

http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:http://browse.geekbench.ca/geekbench2/view/12541

which leads to this (VIA is Tawanese not Japanese):

http://www.via.com.tw/en/products/chipsets/legacy/kt266a/

This leads me to think that VIA694 refers simply to the chipset that the motherboard is using. It could be any mobo by any manufacturer.

You will need to find the exact model number either from the POST screen (use the Pause/Break key to stop the screen before it disappears) or open up the case and look for details printed on the mobo PCB

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you can flash the BIOS but it will probably reset to defaults... So even if you manage to flash it, without the settings they still will not boot. A quite drastic solution would be to customize the ROMs you are going to flash, but seeing you cannot reflashyour backup, that might be a moot point.